# Mobile Version of Login Page?

Tags: mobile, intuit-partner-platform

Currently we've got our Intuit Anywhere app set up so that clients authenticate using the IPP-supplied Login button, which sends them to the Intuit site to enter their credentials. I'd like to start giving clients access to parts of our app via mobile devices; however, they are STILL going to need to authenticate in the same manner. Is the Intuit login page somehow set up to detect mobile devices or is there another URL Intuit makes available with a mobile version of the page?

Thanks in advance for any info.

Norman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the login page will detect it is mobile and render correctly.

regards,
jarred

Comment: Jarred: Thanks for posting but I'm finding it doesn't seem to work; i.e. the "regular" login page is rendered in the mobile browser. Clearly it's something I'm doing (or not doing) but do you know of any settings or modifications I need to make to the javascript to let the Intuit site know I'm using a mobile browser?

Comment: what device are you using to look at the site?

Comment: Jarred: I think the issue is the way the IA app works: my CONTROLLER does a CreateRequest and then RedirectToProvider so that the request isn't really coming from a mobile browser. I know it's not your problem, I've submitted a support ticket to see if I can "force" the mobile view. If you care to (and I understand this is not your problem) I've described the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847177/openid-createrequest-to-simulate-mobile-browser. If I reissue the openid call from the mobile emulator then I see the mobile page.